# Select join mysql 2 databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I'm having some problem with CodeIgniter and joining 2 tables from 2 differents databases.

My first database : `values.companyname.be`

My second database : `int.companyname.be`

So i'm trying to join these two databases with code igniter (or simply in php) and MySQL.

I've got that query but it didn't work.

```
    public function get_values(){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT a.id,a.foreign_id,b.id,b.name FROM values.companyname.be a INNER JOIN int.companyname.be b ON a.foreign_id = b.id');

        return $query;
    }
```

When I tried to execute it, my website is showing me this :

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.be a INNER JOIN int.activeme.be b ON a.company_id = b.id' at
>   line 1

```
SELECT a.id,a.foreign_id,b.id,b.name FROM values.companyname.be a
INNER JOIN int.companyname.be b ON a.foreign_id = b.id
```

I think that the error occurs because of the dots in the databases name.

Comment: use backticks character (`) around database name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to join two databases!

JOINS are for tables so, unles you have to tables named `values.companyname.be` and `int.companyname.be` your sql query is wrong.

The MySQL error you are getting tells you that the second `.` is not expected. Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.foreign_id, b.id,b.name 
FROM `values.companyname.be`.`coupon` a 
INNER JOIN `int.companyname.be`.`company` b 
ON a.foreign_id = b.id
```

Emphasis on the syntax:

```
`dbnname`.`table.name`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `values.companyname.be` and `int.companyname.be` are your table names. So use `(backtick) around the table names

```
SELECT
     a.id,a.foreign_id,b.id,b.name
FROM `values.companyname.be` a
INNER JOIN `int.companyname.be` b
ON a.foreign_id = b.id
```

Comment: the sql parser will look for a table called `values.companyname.be` in this case (and won't find it).

Answer (score 0):

If your database name actually has dots in it (why would you do this to yourself?) then I you will need to use the `backticks` around the database names.

Its not clear though from your query which dots are part of database names and which are to join databases to tables.